# XSLT - unmapped fields at bottom of html

Tags: asp.net, xslt

I have an XML document which references a XSL file for the output of HTML.

In the XSL file I have put in various `"<xsl:value-of select="fieldname" />"` tags referencing items in my XML File.

However for the items I have **not mapped** they just appear as a long string at the bottom of the html page?

Do I really need to omit all my xml data items not referenced in the XSL file for them to go away or is there a trick to this or a bug in my XSL file?

j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is result of the XSLT Processing Model**.

XSLT uses its *built-in templates` if a node should be processed and no template in the XSLT code is matching it. The built-in template that matches a text node copies it.

**Solution**:

Add this template that overrides the XSLT built-in template for text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

This causes any text node not matched by a more specific template in the code (and not copied with `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:value-of`) to be ignored ("deleted").

Comment: The alternative is to avoid processing the items you don't want output, by being selective about which you select in your xsl:apply-templates instructions.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes, definitely. In conditions where no XML document or XSLT code, or wanted result is provided, one cannot be more specific.